# JSON schema: Property must exist *anywhere* at a lower level

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is it possible to validate a json-schema requiring at least one occurrence of a certain property/value at a lower level?

For the json code at the bottom, I can get the schema to require a `C` in a specific subschema:

```
{
    "if": {
        "has_C": {
            "const": true
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "properties": {
            "subschemas": {
                "properties": {
                    "subschema_1": {
                        "required": ["C"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

… or in all subschemas:

```
…
    "then": {
        "properties": {
            "subschemas": {
                "patternProperties": {
                    "^subschema_[0-9]$": {
                        "required": ["C"]
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

… but what schema validates when there is (at least) one instance of `C` in any of the subschemas? As it should also validate when there are more than one (both in `subschema_1` and `subschema_2`), I thought of `"contains"`, but I don't get that working correctly (apart from or because of the question at what level it should be included).

```
{
    "item_1": {
        "has_C": true,
        "subschemas": {
            "subschema_1": {
                "A": 1,
                "B": "a string",
                "C": "a value"
            },
            "subschema_2": {
                "A": 0,
                "B": "another string"
            }
        }
    },
    "item_2": {
        "has_C": false,
        "subschemas": {
            "subschema_1": {
                "B": "a third string"
            },
            "subschema_2": {
                "A": 0,
                "B": "something else"
            }
        }
    },
    "item_3": {
        "has_C": false,
        "subschemas": {
            "subschema_1": {
                "C": "this should not validate"
            }
        }
    },
    "item_4": {
        "has_C": true,
        "subschemas": {
            "subschema_1": {
                "A": 0,
                "B": "this should not validate"
            },
            "subschema_2": {
                "B": "still no C"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "… but how do I require only one instances of C in any subschema? More than one is okay, too ..." I am not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: @Clemens My bad, apologies; I refrased it. I need it to validate when `"has_C"` is true and there is a `"C"` in at least one of the lower levels. With `"has_C": false` there must be no `"C"` in that item. Hope it is clearer this way!